# Which one is better? Stack direction="horizontal" or display flex in react bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, stack, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I think the two functions are the same, but I mostly use display flex instead of Stack in react boostrap because it's more flexible in spacing objects.

Can anyone explain in more detail about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well you can consider display flex as the better solution because in
> the stack direction you will need to re-create the stacks if the view
> port is changed where else in display flex you can give
> `flex-wrap:wrap;` and it will automatically adjust  the flow.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me to choose which function is better for my future project, I appreciate that :)